# Bestsellers of current month rest api

Tags: magento-2.1.7, best-seller

I need to get bestsellers products for the current month. I use `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection`, but I get bestsellers for all months, I used the following code to get it for current month

```
$collection = $this->productCollection->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\Collection'); 
$data=array();
    $collection->setPeriod('monthly');
    //$collection->setPeriod('year');


    $currentMonth = date('Y-m');
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        if($item['period'] == $currentMonth){
            array_push($data,$item->getData());
        }

    }
```

but that code will take more time for every coming month.

Is there a way to get products of current month directly from database?